# How to boot OS X on MacBook 2009 with broken internal keyboard?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

I recently pulled my old MacBooks 2009 out of the closet. Not sure what the exact model is, but anyways, a few years ago I spilled water on the keyboard, so most of the keys don't work anymore. (Sadly the special keys don't work either, like option, command, and control.) Before I stopped using it, I wiped the internal drive, for security purposes.

But now I need OS X for certain work I am doing (Objective C programming for a large scale project,etc). I have the DMG file, which I had on a backup, for OS X El Capitan. I used my Ubuntu machine to convert the DMG to an ISO, and then put then burnt OS X on to a USB. I plugged it in to the macbook, started it up, held down the option key (on an external keyboard) and it didn't work. Any idea on how to fix this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: External USB, not Bluetooth? Are you sure the option key you held down is the Apple option key. If your keyboard is an old Dell, or similar you might need to hold down Ctrl instead to get the bootup chooser running.

Comment: DMG of what exactly? Is it an installer of some sort? I'm confused as to where this came from, as AFAIK, no bootable image for macOS is distributed in a DMG.

Comment: The terminal utility for making OS X install mediums allows you to create a DMG.

Comment: Was the external keyboard an Apple keyboard or a PC keyboard? I believe there is a difference with respect to the option key.

Comment: @david-anderson, it was a a typical PC keyboard, num pad, etc

Comment: I have a 2007 iMac with a keyboard from a HP PC plugged into the USB port. Everything works OK, except when trying to boot to the Mac Startup Manager. Holding down the Alt key does not work. I have borrow a Apple USB keyboard from a different Mac when I want to do this.